# Model converges to 0.5 during transfer learning

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

When I retrain a binary classification model after training a model once, the model always converges to predicting 0.5. Initially, after the first epoch, the output of the model is already predicting the same value (0.68), before slowly trending towards 0.5.

The model is loaded through `keras.models.load_model("oldModel.h5")` and cloned to keep the old model around for use through `keras.models.clone_model(model)`.

The dataset is loaded in exactly the same way during the retraining as it was in the inital training run, through 1. loading filenames and labels into pandas series, 2. loading into tensors, 3. loading the images through a partial call, with caching and prefetching to help training performance.

Besides decreasing the learning rate, all other parameters such as trainable layers and loss functions are kept constant throughout both training processes. Trainable layers are the same, and only consist of the top few layers of the model.

I have checked the training dataset to check if the output is correct, and it is as expected.

#### Code to load dataset

```
X_train_file = self.df[self.df.subset=="train"].fileName
Y1 = self.df[self.df.subset=="train"].meanElicat
Y2 = self.df[self.df.subset=="train"].finalY.astype(int)
        
X_test_file = self.df[self.df.subset=="val"].fileName
Y1_test = self.df[self.df.subset=="val"].meanElicat
Y2_test = self.df[self.df.subset=="val"].finalY.astype(int)
      
train_image_paths = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_train_file, dtype=tf.string)
train_Y1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(Y1)
train_Y2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(Y2)
        
test_image_paths = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_test_file, dtype=tf.string)
test_Y1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(Y1_test)
test_Y2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(Y2_test)
        
train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(  ( train_image_paths,  (train_Y1,train_Y2)  )  )

test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(  ( test_image_paths,  (test_Y1,test_Y2)  ) )
        
def map_fn(path, label):
    image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file(path))
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [300, 300])
    return image, label
        
self.train_ds = train.map(partial(map_fn), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE).batch(16).cache().prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
self.val_ds = test.map(partial(map_fn), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE).batch(16).cache().prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

#### Code to train and fit the model

```
self.model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(eval(lr)), 
              loss = {'classification': tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()},
              metrics = {'classification': ["accuracy", tf.keras.metrics.AUC(),]})

filepath = os.path.join("weights", f"{str(weightName)}_{blocks:02d}_CW[{cw}]" + 
                        ".E[{epoch}]_{val_loss:.4f}.h5")
callbacks = [
            CSVLogger(weights,blocks,cw, self.logName), 
             tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=patience), 
             tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, 
                                                save_best_only=True, 
                                                save_weights_only=False)]

try:
    self.model.fit(self.train_ds, epochs=epoch, callbacks=callbacks, 
              validation_data=self.val_ds, 
              verbose = 2)
except Exception as e:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

#### Output of retrained model after 1 epoch

```
array([[0.6818546 ],
       [0.6817692 ],
       [0.68143094],
       [0.6824522 ],
       [0.6820409 ],
       [0.6816176 ],
       [0.68077767],
       [0.68115866],
       ...
```

#### Output of retrained model after 11 epochs

```
array([[0.4997447 ],
       [0.49965417],
       [0.5004351 ],
       [0.49858376],
       [0.49974793],
       [0.500144  ],
       [0.50129014],
       [0.5004081 ],
       ...
```

#### Output of model chosen for retraining after first training process

```
array([[0.01635163],
       [0.8146548 ],
       [0.08911347],
       [0.03006527],
       [0.04414936],

        ...

       [0.8874662 ],
       [0.37499326],
       [0.98350084],
       [0.9966594 ],
       [0.09798203]], dtype=float32)
```

Thank you for any help rendered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was from `keras.clone_model(model)` which requires the input tensor to be specified. To save on time I just read the model anytime I wanted to use it.